# Is replacing a dead worker chosen randomly?

Tags: banished

In many guides you can read that you should place some buildings near working places (e.g. farmers).

So when one farmer dies, he is replaced by one worker.

**Is then one of those workers chosen by their distance of their home to their new working place or is it chosen randomly?**

Because if its not, this advice wouldn't be that good for big cities. :)

Answer (score 8):

I can't find the source, but I read replacement workers are chosen randomly. **But** you can force a 'smart' reassignation by :

- pausing
- setting all your workers to labourers
- unpausing a few seconds
- reassigning your workers

Do **not** unassign your teachers, otherwise all the students will leave school.

And I have a source for that : http://www.reddit.com/r/Banished/comments/1z0h8t/increase_efficiency_with_worker_location/ !

So the advice is good even for big cities, if you take the time to do the smart reassignation.

Comment: Awesome! I really would like to mark your question as correct, but it doesn't answer my question. Still this was what I am looking for. Big props!